# How to bind a datagrid column to a combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding, datagrid

I'm trying to set up the following player collection and I'm having trouble displaying/updating the data collection.
I have 2 classes: CountryModel and PlayerModel
The CountryModel class is defined as follows:

```
public static class CountryModel
    {
        public class Country
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Abbr { get; set; }
            public byte[] Flag { get; set; }
        }

        public static async Task<ObservableCollection<Country>> GetCountriesAsync()
        {
            // Get all country names from system
            var ThreeLetterMapping = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
                                        .Select(ci => new RegionInfo(ci.LCID))
                                        .GroupBy(ri => ri.EnglishName)
                                        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First().ThreeLetterISORegionName);
            // Create observablecollection to contain list of country names
            ObservableCollection<Country> getNames = new ObservableCollection<Country>();
            // Run task of getting every country files
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // Get all files from Resources directory
                string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Resources\");
                foreach (string Name in Files)
                {
                    // Add only country name without extension if png format
                    if (Path.GetExtension(Name) == ".png" && !Name.Contains("BCA"))
                    {

                        byte[] image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Name);


                        // Country name without extension
                        string CountryName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Name);
                        // Get abbreviation from above ThreeLetterMapping variable
                        string abbr = null;
                        try
                        {
                            // Country exists and mapping is possible
                            abbr = ThreeLetterMapping[CountryName];
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            // Custom mapping to 3 letter using first 3 letters in country name
                            abbr = CountryName.Substring(0, 3);
                        }
                        // Add country with data to list
                        getNames.Add(new Country { Name = CountryName, Abbr = abbr, Flag = image });
                        //getNames.Add(new Country { Name = CountryName, Abbr = abbr, Flag = GetFlag(CountryName) });
                    }
                }
            });
            return getNames;
        }

        public static BitmapImage GetFlag(string CountryName)
        {
            try
            {
                BitmapImage getFlag = new BitmapImage(new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Resources\" + CountryName + ".png"));
                //BitmapImage getFlag = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/" + CountryName + ".png"));
                return getFlag;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Message, "Retrieve Flag", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

As you can see from the code above, I can successfully retrieve a `List<CountryModel>` from the above class.

Now my MainWindow looks like this:
[image]

Textboxes are defined as follows:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxId" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Id, ElementName=DataGridPlayers}" IsEnabled="False" Height="26" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,12,0" IsTabStop="False"/>
<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxFullName" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.FullName, ElementName=DataGridPlayers}" IsEnabled="False" Height="26" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,12,0" IsTabStop="False"/>
<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxLastName" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.LastName, ElementName=DataGridPlayers}" Height="26" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,12,0" TabIndex="1"/>
<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxFirstName" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.FirstName, ElementName=DataGridPlayers}" Height="26" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,12,0" TabIndex="2"/>
<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxMiddleName" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.MiddleName, ElementName=DataGridPlayers}" Height="26" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,12,0" TabIndex="3"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxGender" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedItem.Male, ElementName=DataGridPlayers}" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" TabIndex="4">
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Female"/>
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Male"/>
</ComboBox>
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxCountry" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem.Country, ElementName=DataGridPlayers}" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Name" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,12,0" TabIndex="5">
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Width="30" Source="{Binding Flag}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="4,0,0,0"/>
               </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

And the DataGrid is defined as follows:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" x:Name="DataGridPlayers" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray" SelectionChanged="DataGridPlayers_SelectionChanged" TabIndex="12">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MiddleName}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Player full name" Binding="{Binding FullName}" Width="1.5*"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Male}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Country" Binding="{Binding Country}" Width="*"/>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Flag" Width="40" IsReadOnly="True">
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                         <Image Source="{Binding Flag}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGrid.RowStyle>
          <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
               <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Flag}" Value="{x:Null}">
                         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
     </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<CountryModel.Country> ListCountries;
        private ObservableCollection<PlayerModel> ListPlayers;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetCountriesAsync();
            ListPlayers = new ObservableCollection<PlayerModel>();
            DataGridPlayers.ItemsSource = ListPlayers;
        }

        private async void GetCountriesAsync()
        {
            ListCountries = await Task.Run(() => CountryModel.GetCountriesAsync());
            ComboBoxCountry.ItemsSource = ListCountries;
        }

        private void ButtonAddPlayer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PlayerModel newplayer = new PlayerModel { LastName = "Lastname", FirstName = "Firstname", MiddleName = "Middlename", Male = true, Country = "" }; //, Flag = null
            ListPlayers.Add(newplayer);
            DataGridPlayers.SelectedItem = ListPlayers.Last();
        }
    }
```

Now I have several issues with this:
How do I bind the Flag column to the flag image of the country?
Why is it that when I update the fields on the left (for e.g. Lastname or the country) the datagrid is not updated accordingly?

Thank you for taking the time to help!
Jedi Master

Comment: Do you have Fody.PropertyChanged installed? If not you should look at that. If you dont want to install any package, then your models need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Otherwise WPF do not know, that the properties in DataGrid changed via the boxes on the left. You need to notify the WPF about that.

Comment: Great! After some testing I finally went for Fody! Life is so much easier!

Comment: Glad it helped ^.^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second issue:
Your class should look like this, if you dont have Fody installed

I do recommend to look on that. Cleans up the code quite a lot as you can see in example.
https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

Otherwise WPF do not know, that the properties in DataGrid changed via the boxes on the left. You need to notify the WPF about that.

```
    public class Country : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
            }
        }

        private string abbr;

        public string Abbr
        {
            get { return abbr; }
            set
            {
                abbr = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Abbr));
            }
        }

        private string countryName;

        public string CountryName
        {
            get { return countryName; }
            set
            {
                countryName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CountryName));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Flag));
            }
        }

        public BitmapImage Flag => GetFlag(countryName);

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Fody example:

```
    public class Country : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {       
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Abbr { get; set; }

        public string CountryName { get; set; }

        public BitmapImage Flag => GetFlag(CountryName);

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

First issue: when you have your class setup as the example, then you can bind the ImageSource to the Flag.

Comment: I am beginning to understand the purpose of INotifyPropertyChanged. But, as you can see in my post, I do load the Flag images into memory so as not to do frequent access to the files. Isn't that the case in the class definition you wrote above where you added the Flag as a "get" which is constantly going to have file reads?

Comment: Additionally, since I am using `ObservableCollection` when binding to the DataGrid, shouldn't the `INotifyPropertyChanged` already be implemented?

Comment: @JediMaster ObservableCollection notifies on adding, or removing objects into the collection. It does not notify on change of properties inside of those objects. I was confused with that as well, when I began. And about the Flag. Yes it will read the file every time the `CountryName` changes, but I dont see that as a issue. But since you need to react to changes of the property, it would do that anyway. One thing you can do is to make a method, in the model like `.SetNewFlag()`, which would be called in setter of `CountryName` and that would set the flag property and preserve it in memory.

Comment: So it would set it only once on each `CountryName` change. (Sorry for message split, but ran out of characters ☺)